# Wrapping C++ class in Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a C++ library that doesn't use namespaces. I want to port it to Objective-C. The problem is the name collisions between the two. I want it to have the same name in Objective-C that is the name of the C++ object. But, I just can't figure out the best way to do this without it just becoming a mess. I am hoping for a solution to this.

Comment: Why would you need this? Is there no way to use it as it is? What is the target platform?

Comment: where ever objc is usable in. I'm trying to wrap Qt in ObjC so I can use ObjC on Windows, Mac, Linux. NeXTstep's gui is butt ugly. So I wanted a sexier gui for it.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix all your Objective-C classes in the same way as you would writing a framework on the Mac and Apple does with its frameworks.

Comment: both the base class and the class i'm trying to create is both prefixed.

Comment: Well use a different prefix for the OC classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#define` and `#undef` to temporarily rename the classes/functions etc in your code - just make sure they are undef'ed when calling the C++ code.

e.g. in the header(s) for your wrapper have `#define Bar_Function Foo_Function`, then surround the bits of code that call the library's Bar_Function with `#undef Bar_Function` and `#define Bar_Function Foo_Function`

Now the only problem comes when you need to export your own Bar_Function...

Don't do this though - its silly, just work around it. :)

Comment: ... or actually, just use C++ to start with, its better. :)